# MongoDb C# An error occurred while deserializing the property of class

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, json-deserialization, bson

I am trying to retrieve data from local MongoDb with JSON documents like this:

```
{ 
    "teryt_num_code" : "AB",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Alabama"
}
```

I have created a POCO class as following:

```
public class Sensor
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string teryt_num_code { get; set; }
}
```

To retrieve all data from my database I use a method below:

```
public async Task<ICollection<Sensor>> GetAllAsync() => await _collection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
```

but the exception was thrown calling that method:

```
An error occurred while deserializing the property of class Sensor: 
Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class Sensor.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `id` property of your class is mapped to the BSON id (property `_id` on the document). This leaves the `id` property in the MongoDB document without a corresponding property in the POCO. Therefore, the error is raised.

In order to fix the deserialization error, you can apply both a `BsonNoId` and a `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` attribute to the POCO:

```
[BsonNoId]
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Sensor
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string teryt_num_code { get; set; }
}
```

`BsonNoId` disables the convention; therefore BSON `id` is mapped to POCO `id`. `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` fixes the error that the driver does not know how to deserialize the `_id` property that every MongoDB document contains.